# Selenium crashing (chrome & firefox) within a flask route on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, selenium

Running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server

Trying to save a screenshot via selenium within a flask route.

Issue is no matter what I try it crashes.

Using `--headless`

```
@api.route('/image/<path:encoded_url>.png')
def generate_image(encoded_url):
    """
    Returns an image (PNG) of a URL. The URL is encoded in the path of the image being requested.
    """
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

    options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-using")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(f"{os.getcwd()}/chromedriver", options=options)

    url = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(encoded_url)

    driver.get(url if "http" in url else "https://" + url)
    driver.set_window_size(1200, 630)

    while True:
        x = driver.execute_script("return document.readyState")
        if x == "complete":
            break
   

    driver.save_screenshot("screen.png")
    driver.close()

    return send_file("screen.png", mimetype='image/png')
```

I've tried everything but firefox exits with error 127 (not much online regarding this)

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 127
```

I've tried running with Xvfb with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after trying a whole load of options it turns out the issue was with my setup of gunicorn.

go to

`cd /etc/systemd/system/`

open the service you made for guinocorn

`sudo nano  {servicename}`

The issue was the Environment line

Originally I has it as this:

```
Environment="PATH=/home/ubuntu/retrotex/environment/bin"
```

But once I changed it to the below everything worked:

```
Environment="PATH=/home/ubuntu/retrotex/environment/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
```

It seems that flask didn't have access to the folders needed to run chome or selenium.

Make sure you run the below to reload the service after

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart {service_name}
```

What a waste of a day.