# /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, vps

so I have this selenium and flask application that I deployed on digital ocean ubuntu VPS. when I run the application in development mode "main@ubutu$python3 pyfile.py" everything runs perfectly without throwing any error. But when I run the application on production mode, i.e when the app is deployed I get the following error.

```
The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed
```

I have the latest google-chrome and chromedriver.

```
main@ubuntu:~$ google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 102.0.5005.61
```

also in my code, I have included all the options that are required to run on a VPS without display.

```
option = Options()
    service = Service("/home/path/to/chromedriver")
    #option.binary_location = "/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable"
    option.add_argument("--headless")
    option.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    option.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
    option.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
    option.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    option.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    option.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=option)
```

many people have experienced this problem but the option --no-sandbox and --headless seemed to have solved their problems. but even after that I still have the same issue.
google-chrome path /urs/bin/google-chrome.
any help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: ssame issue, did you solved it ?

Comment: yes, the solution is the first answer

Answer (score 0):

I was using digital ocean ubuntu VPS, so I followed their documentation on how to deploy flask applications on their servers. if at all you are following their documentation and you run into this. here is the solution.
[thanks to @Lewis Morris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68128285/selenium-crashing-chrome-firefox-within-a-flask-route-on-ubuntu-20-04)

the problem was the path ENVIRONMENT_PATH that I used in the /etc/systemd/system/myapp.service, initially, it was

```
 Environment="PATH=/home/main/searchapp/venv/bin
```

then I changed it to:

```
Environment="PATH=/home/main/searchapp/venv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
```

hope it helps someone in the future so they don't have to waste their time.